# extract rows from one file based on values from another file - LINUX

Tags: linux

I am new to linux, and got this elementary question,,,

I would like to extract rows from a text file-A BASED on another text file-B containing the values of gene name (ABD, GHE)

so the output would be

```
chr gene start stop pval
    2   ABD  5667  5789 0.03
    5   GHE  4556  4784 0.34
```

file A

```
chr gene start stop pval
1   xic  455   467 0.005
2   ABD  5667  5789 0.03
5   GHE  4556  4784 0.34
```

file B

```
ABD
GHE
```

Thanks
M

Comment: People are gonna propose awk solutions, but the best thing you can do is use Python and be happy.

Comment: thanks but I am working on a linux server... and that why i am specific

Comment: Linux is the type of operating system. Awk and Python are programs that can run on it. Although for this, I would think a `read line` loop and `grep` will be a popular answer. Are you using bash as the shell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

```
head -n 1 A ; grep -f B A
chr gene start stop pval
2   ABD  5667  5789 0.03
5   GHE  4556  4784 0.34
```

Comment: now to direct the file to an output i would use >> right ?

Comment: The output to a file... yes. One will overwrite an existing file, >> will append. But that should really be a new question :}